# obtain total travel duration given startPoint and endPoint using google maps api 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

how can I retrieve total travel time and distance using google maps api 3 given two points ? I mean I'm looking for in google api documentation but I didn't find what I expected to find or I'm very confused about all google function.could someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

When you have only a startpoint and an endpoint you may fetch **distance** and **duration** out of the 1st leg of the 1st route, because the DirectionsResult will only contain 1 route with 1 leg when you didn't define any waypoints.

[Example-Route from Chicago to Los Angeles:](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Chicago,IL&destination=Los%20Angeles,CA&sensor=false)

You see, leg#1 of route#1 contains:
**distance:** 2.015 miles
**duration:** 1 day, 8 hours

Comment: You're not providing any sort of API Key -- any idea what sorts of costs and/or thresholds there are on this API?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Directions API. It will give you a list of steps with duration and distance on each step, add those and you will get total travel time: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#JSON

Comment: Just add all durations together and you will get total time.
pseudocode:
`var total_time = 0;
for(step in steps){
   total_time = total_time + step.duration;
}`